# Apply Benders decomposition approach in CPLEX with python while using docplex class

Tags: python, cplex, benders-decomposition

I am new to cplex with python. I want to solve a problem using the Benders decomposition approach. Where I want to use  UserCutCallback and LazyConstraintCallback. I am writing code in script format (which means I am not defining class, object, etc.). Would I be able to code my problem in that format while using  UserCutCallback and LazyConstraintCallback? If yes, how can I use  UserCutCallback and LazyConstraintCallback? My problem is as follows:

## Defining Model

```
my_bdrex_OP=Model('My Original Model',log_output=True)
```

## Defining Variables

```
x_1=my_bdrex_OP.integer_var(name='x_1', lb=0)
x_2=my_bdrex_OP.integer_var(name='x_2', lb=0)
y_1=my_bdrex_OP.continuous_var(name='y_1', lb=0)
y_2=my_bdrex_OP.continuous_var(name='y_2', lb=0)
y_3=my_bdrex_OP.continuous_var(name='y_3', lb=0)
```

## Adding constraints

```
my_bdrex_OP.add_constraint(2*x_1+4*x_2+4*y_1-2*y_2+3*y_3<=12)
my_bdrex_OP.add_constraint(3*x_1+5*x_2+2*y_1+3*y_2-y_3<=10)
my_bdrex_OP.add_constraint(x_1<=2)
my_bdrex_OP.add_constraint(x_2<=2)
```

## Defining Objective function

```
objective_OP=4*x_1+7*x_2+2*y_1-3*y_2+y_3
my_bdrex_OP.maximize(objective_OP)
```

## Solving

```
my_bdrex_OP.print_information()
print(my_bdrex_OP.export_as_lp_string())
```

I am solving the above problem by using the Benders strategy:

```
my_bdrex_OP.parameters.benders.strategy = 3
my_bdrex_OP.solve()
my_bdrex_OP.print_solution()
```

And I successfully got the solution.

But I want to solve it by using the UserCutCallback and LazyConstraintCallback method. I request to the community please help to understand the use of UserCutCallback and LazyConstraintCallback to solve the problem in the Benders decomposition technique.

Answer (score 1):

For the implementation issue in UserCutCallback & LazyConstraintCallback, you might refer this github
[Python Example](https://github.com/cswaroop/cplex-samples/blob/master/admipex5.py)

For technique detail between both Callback functions, you also can refer [CPLEX Official website](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/icos/20.1.0?topic=techniques-user-cut-lazy-constraint-pools)

Hope those information is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

CPLEX ships with sample source code in multiple languages. If you go to /cplex/examples/src/python, you four examples doing Benders decomposition: benders.py; bendersatsp.py; bendersatsp2.py; and facility.py.